# How would I go about removing a word with brackets and all other brackets in those brackets in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

Is there a way? I want

```
"windows": [
            { "x": 2, "y": 0 }
        ]
```

to end up as nothing. I want the same to happen if there are more coordinates in brackets too.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+H
Find what: (?:^|(?<=]))[^][]*?(?=[|$)
Replace with: LEAVE EMPTY
check Wrap around
check Regular expression
Replace all

Explanation:

(    ?:         # start non capture group
   ^          # beginning of line
   |          # OR
  (?<=])  # positive lookbehind, zero-length assertion that
  make sure we have a closing square bracket   before
     )           # end group
   [^][]*?     # negative character class, any character that is 
   not openning or closing square bracket, may appear 0 or more times, not greedy

(?=         # start positive lookahead, zero-length assertion 
                 that make sure we have after
   [           # an openning square bracket
     |           # OR
    $           # end of line
     )          # ed lookahead

Result for given example:

[A B C][D E F][G H I]
[J K L] M N O][P Q R [S T U]

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^\h*"windows":\h*\[\s+{.+?}\s+\]\s+`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
  \h*           # 0 or more horizontal spaces
  "windows":    # literally
  \h*           # 0 or more horizontal spaces
  \[            # opening square bracket
  \s+           # 1 or more any spaces, including linebreak
  {             # opening brace
  .+?           # 1 or more any character, not greedy
  }             # closing brace
  \s+           # 1 or more any spaces, including linebreak
  \]            # closing square bracket
  \s+           # 1 or more any spaces, including linebreak
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]